# Groovy Syntax when setting img src in gsp

Tags: gsp

I am trying to change my image source based on the current controller. I could hard code it in with the direct file path for each individual image but I want to see if the following works:

```
 <img class="imageTest" src="${controllerName == 'testboard' ? ${resource(base: session['brandingBasePath'], dir: 'styles/ui/pictures', file: 'board1.png')} : ${resource(base: session['brandingBasePath'], dir: 'styles/ui/picture', file: 'board2.png')}};
```

I get an error when trying this, but I am sort of a beginner with this language. Any ideas on getting this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Oops, found my problem. You don't need to repeat the ${} (what are these even called) for each function.

```
 <img class="imageTest" src="${controllerName == 'testboard' ? resource(base: session['brandingBasePath'], dir: 'styles/ui/pictures', file: 'board1.png') : resource(base: session['brandingBasePath'], dir: 'styles/ui/picture', file: 'board2.png')};
```

That would work.